# Usar um focus para vários campos.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bom dia, criei uma função para validar o cnpj no meu formulário e preciso usar um focus() para o cursor fique no input quando o usurário digitar o cnpj errado, mas existe 3 campos distintos de cnpj. Já fiz de vários jeito, mas ele só aceita no primeiro campo.

jquery:

```
jQuery.fn.validacnpj = function () {
this.change(function () {
    CNPJ = $(this).val();
    if (!CNPJ) {
        return false;
    }
    erro = new String;
    if (CNPJ == "00.000.000/0000-00") {
        erro += "CNPJ inválido\n\n";
    }
    CNPJ = CNPJ.replace(".", "");
    CNPJ = CNPJ.replace(".", "");
    CNPJ = CNPJ.replace("-", "");
    CNPJ = CNPJ.replace("/", "");

    var a = [];
    var b = new Number;
    var c = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2];
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        a[i] = CNPJ.charAt(i);
        b += a[i] * c[i + 1];
    }
    if ((x = b % 11) < 2) {
        a[12] = 0
    } else {
        a[12] = 11 - x
    }
    b = 0;
    for (y = 0; y < 13; y++) {
        b += (a[y] * c[y]);
    }
    if ((x = b % 11) < 2) {
        a[13] = 0;
    } else {
        a[13] = 11 - x;
    }
    if ((CNPJ.charAt(12) != a[12]) || (CNPJ.charAt(13) != a[13])) {
        erro += "Dígito verificador com problema!";
    }
    if (erro.length > 0) {
        $(this).val('');
        alert(erro);
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#cnpj").focus();
        });

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(this).focus()
        }, 100);
    }
    return $(this);
});
```

};

index:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Formulário de Cadastro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-validacpfecnpj.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/util.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 1230px; margin-top: -8px  ">
        <div class="logo">
            <img alt="Logo Prefeitura" src="img/bg_header_logo.png" >
        </div>

        <form action="processaCadastro.php" method="post" name="formCadastro" id="formCadastro">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Dados do Condomínio</legend>

                <div class="groupItemForm">
                    <div class="itemForm">
                        <label class="lblCondominio">Nome do condomínio ou edifício:</label>
                        <label class="lblFieldAlert">*</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemInputForm4">
                        <input type="text" name="nomeCondominio" placeholder="condomínio/edifício" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="groupItemForm">
                    <label>Possue CNPJ?</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="checkCNPJ" id="checkCNPJ" value="nao" /><label>Não</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="checkCNPJ" id="checkCNPJ" value="sim" checked="checked" /><label>Sim</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cnpj" class="cnpj" id="cnpj" placeholder="xx.xxx.xxx/xxxx-xx"  />
                </div>

                <div class="groupItemForm">
                    <div class="itemForm">
                        <label>Telefone:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemInputForm1">
                        <input type="tel" class="fixo" name="telCondominio" placeholder="(xx) xxxx-xxxx">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="groupItemForm">
                    <div class="itemForm">
                        <label>Celular:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemInputForm1">
                        <input type="tel" class="cell" name="celCondominio" placeholder="(xx) xxxxx-xxxx">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Dados do Síndico</legend>

                <div class="groupItemForm">
                    <div class="itemForm">
                        <label>Nome do Síndico:</label><label class="lblFieldAlert">*</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemInputForm3">
                        <input type="text" name="nomeSindico" required >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="groupItemForm">
                    <div class="itemForm">
                        <label>CPF do Síndico:</label><label class="lblFieldAlert">*</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemInputForm1">
                        <input type="text" id="cpf" class="cpf" name="cpfSindico" required >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="groupItemForm">
                    <div class="itemForm">
                        <label>E-mail:</label><label class="lblFieldAlert">*</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemInputForm3">
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="groupItemForm">
                    <div class="itemForm">
                        <label>Confirmação de E-mail:</label><label class="lblFieldAlert">*</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemInputForm3">
                        <input type="email" name="emailConfirm" id="emailConfirm" required >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="groupItemForm">
                    <div class="itemForm">
                        <label>Telefone:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemInputForm1">
                        <input type="text" class="fixo" name="telSindico" placeholder="(xx) xxxx-xxxx">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="groupItemForm">
                    <div class="itemForm">
                        <label>Celular 1:</label><label class="lblFieldAlert">*</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemInputForm1">
                        <input type="tel" class="cell" name="cel1Sindico" placeholder="(xx) xxxxx-xxxx" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="groupItemForm">
                    <div class="itemForm">
                        <label>Celular 2:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemInputForm1">
                        <input type="tel" class="cell" name="cel2Sindico" placeholder="(xx) xxxxx-xxxx">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Outras Informações</legend>

                <div class="groupItemForm">
                    <label>Tem administradora de condomínio contratada?</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="admCondominio" value="nao" required><label>Não</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="admCondominio" value="sim" checked="checked" required><label>Sim</label>
                    <div class="itemInputDoubleForm1">
                        <input type="text" name="empr_adm" class="empr_adm" id="empr_adm" placeholder="Nome da administradora" />
                        <label>CNPJ</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cnpj_adm" class="cnpj" id="cnpjadmin" placeholder="xx.xxx.xxx/xxxx-xx"  />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="groupItemForm">
                    <label>Tem empresa de manutenção de elevadores contratada?</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="manutancaoElevador" value="nao" required><label>Não</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="manutancaoElevador" value="sim" checked="checked" required><label>Sim</label>
                    <div class="itemInputDoubleForm2">
                        <input type="text" name="empr_manut" class="empr_manut" id="empr_manut" placeholder="Nome da empresa" />
                        <label>CNPJ</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cnpj_manut" class="cnpj" id="cnpjmanut" placeholder="xx.xxx.xxx/xxxx-xx"  />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="groupItemForm">
                    <label>Há interesse em participar de palestra abordando as obrigações tributárias?</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="participacacao" value="nao" ><label>Não</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="participacacao" value="sim" checked="checked" ><label>Sim</label><br><br>
                    <div class="itemInputCheckboxForm">
                        <div class="itemForm">
                            <label>Período desejado para participar da palestra:</label>
                        </div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="turnoPalestraManha" value="Sim" ><label>Manhã</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="turnoPalestraTarde" value="Sim" ><label>Tarde</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="turnoPalestraNoite" value="Sim" ><label>Noite</label><br>

                        <div class="groupItemForm">
                            <div class="itemForm">
                                <label>Número de interessados:</label>
                                <input type="number" name="numeroDeParticipantes" placeholder="Nº Interessados" min="1" ><br><br>
                                <label class="lblFieldAlert"><b>AVISO! Em breve será enviado via e-mail o calendário de palestras para reserva de vagas.</b></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <br>
            <label>Códgio</label><br>

            <img src="/common/rotinas_php/Gerajpeg/Gerajpeg.php"><br>
            <input type=text id="letras" name="letras" required size="4" maxlength="5">
            <br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">

            <div class="groupItemForm">

            </div>
        </form>

        <footer style="margin-bottom: 30px">
            <hr style="margin-top: 30px">  
            <div class="img_prefeitura" style="float:left">
                <img src="img/logo_portalfinancas.png">
            </div>

            <div class="footer_dados" style="float: right; font-family: Arial;">
                <div style="color: darkblue; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold"> Secretaria de Finaças </div>
                <div style="color: darkblue">Cais do Apolo, 14º andar, Bairro do Recife</div>
                <div style="color: darkblue">Recife-PE, CEP 50030-903</div>
                <div style="color: darkblue; margin-top: 10px">Teleatendimento: (81) 3355-8261</div>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: O identificador `id` deve ser único em cada página, se trocar o `id` aí poderá dar o `focus()` onde bem entender...

Comment: Já tentei fazer assim, mas não pegou

Answer (score 1):

Algumas observações sobre seu código:

- Usando document.ready em local incorreto: isso não será executado dentro do seu bloco de código:

  ```
  if (erro.length > 0) {
      $(this).val('');
      alert(erro);
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#cnpj").focus();
      });    // resto do código omitido
  ```

O evento "ready" é do document e não vai ser impactado pelo seu `if`.

- Dois focus: você está usando primeiro um `$("#cnpj").focus();`, que claramente vai posicionar o focus no elemento com id "cnpj", independente de quem esteja com erro, o correto, já que você está validando o próprio input seria `$(this).focus()` apenas.
- Escope do `this`: cada function tem seu próprio escope, e provavelmente o `this` dentro da function com `setTimeout` não é o mesmo, então `this` não significa o mesmo objeto. Tente associar o `this` a uma variável, assim:

  ```
  alert(erro);
  var elem = $(this);
  setTimeout(function () { elem.focus(); }, 100);
  ```

Acredito que isso vai resolver o seu problema.